# I want to convert a terrain mesh to a displaced plane so i can add google maps image texture

Tags: mesh, texturing, modifiers, height-map

I want to make a game which is a bit like GTA but in my home town.

I'm making the map in Blender. I found a 3d model from my towns website for geological data, it is CAD file, consisting of polygons.

I also have a high res Google maps image which I want to put onto the terrain so I can see where the roads and trees are so I can continue making the map.

I've tried to convert the terrain mesh into a heightmap, put it on a plain and then applying the texture but that gave me weird results and I tried it multiple times with different settings. I've also tried projection painting but I don't really understand how to do it and when I just followed a tutorial it didn't work.
Blender GIS addon doesnt give me high enough height map or texture resolution I need a way to turn my terrain mesh into a heightmap or better yet directly into a displaced plane.

[image]

This is just a screenshot of the high res image, the original has a much higher resolution and is a bit bigger

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Displace Modifier to apply the heightmap to your plane?  Perhaps yes as you mention "applying texture"

Comment: @james_t i would do that but i do not have a heightmap yet. I need help baking a high-res height/normal map from the mesh i do have from the geo data